# Python. Is it possible to make a one-liner from a loop where value of a variable constantly increases?

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

I'm sorry if I initiate asking a duplicate question but found nothing on this. If the question can be asked in a different manner feel free to suggest or edit, please.

The goal is to convert any n-based integer to a decimal integer.

```
from string import digits, ascii_uppercase


def convert_n_to_10(number, n):
    alphabet = digits + ascii_uppercase
    result_10 = 0
    for i in range(len(str(number))):
        result_10 = result_10 * n + alphabet.index(str(number)[i])
    return result_10
```

The question is about possibility of making a one-liner from this loop where value of the result_10 variable constantly increases.

```
for i in range(len(str(number))):
    result_10 = result_10 * n + alphabet.index(str(number)[i])
```

Thank you.

Comment: where was `x` defined? And why is `number` an unused argument?

Comment: Why not just use the `int` function in place of `convert_n_to_10`? It already does what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JosephSible: no, **int** assumes that the characters are in base 10 already.  The desired routine also takes the radix as an argument.  Consider converting "21101" from trinary into decimal.

Comment: @Prune int takes a second parameter to specify the base of the input.

Comment: Ah ... forgot about that.  Right you are!  My mistake.

Comment: Damn. Tried to edit part of code to ask a question and didn't notice all the vars. My bad.

Comment: Check out `reduce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's straight-forward to turn your

```
    result_10 = 0
    for i in range(len(str(number))):
        result_10 = result_10 * n + alphabet.index(str(number)[i])
    return result_10
```

into this:

```
    return reduce(lambda result_10, i: result_10 * n + alphabet.index(str(number)[i]),
                  range(len(str(number))),
                  0)
```

Note that I simply copied&pasted the main parts (the computation expression, the iterable, and the initial value) without even reading them.

(In Python 3, you need to import `reduce` from the `functools` module.)

Comment: The computations are 100% correct, thanks for your notice. Since the question was about dynamic variable alteration with using previous computation results your answer is the one I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
return sum([pow(n, len(x)-i) * alphabet.index(x[i])
           for i in range(len(x))])
```

Compute the proper power of **n** for each position in the number (which as already a string; no need to convert) and multiply by the digit value.

Even better, as JosephSible reminded us:

```
return int(x, n)
```

Comment: It seems we should divide the `sum` by `n` to have a correct answer.

Comment: `return int(x, n)` works perfect. As JosephSible wrote.